# How to collect selected Gridview items to move to next fragment for payment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am working on payment functionality. I have `GridView` with `CheckBox` on each items. I need to bring selected grid items to next fragment & do some calculation.
I tried like below

```
btnPtoPay.Click += delegate
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tableGrid.ChildCount; x++)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCellFive);
        var tvSelectedAmount = (TextView)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCelltwo);
        var tvAmountPaid = (TextView)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCelltwo);
        decimal totalM = 0; 
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {                        
            totalM = totalM+ Convert.ToDecimal(tvSelectedAmount.Text);   
            //Here how to get selected item, with all fields
        }
    };

    var fragmentTx = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    var feePay = new FeePaymentFragment();
    fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.crealtabcontent, feePay, "feedPayFragmentTag").AddToBackStack("feePayfrg");
    fragmentTx.Commit();
};
```

How can I get selected items?

See screenshot for more information

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code where you have made this ui and also the axml for the same?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be achieved by basic OOP practices. Create a container object for each item, and pass all the checked items to the new fragment via the constructor. Here is a very basic example, based off of the code you presented in your question:

### Container

```
class LineItem
{
    //you should probably have an id in here to differentiate objects easier

    public double TotalFee { get; }
    public double AmountPaid { get; }
    public double SelectedAmount { get; }
    public LineItem(double totalFee, double amountPaid, double selectedAmount)
    {
        TotalFee = totalFee;
        AmountPaid = amountPaid;
        SelectedAmount = selectedAmount;
    }
}
```

The above class just acts as a container so you can pass data around and retrieve it in an efficient and verbose manner.

### Fragment Class

```
class FeePaymentFragment : Fragment
{
    private List<LineItem> _selectedList;

    public FeePaymentFragment(List<LineItem> selectedList)
    {
        _selectedList = selectedList;
    }

    //do the rest of your fragment stuff, referencing _selectedList when you
    //need to access the selected objects
}
```

The above class is your fragment class; the important note is the constructor which accepts a list of `LineItem` objects. This is so you can reference them when needed.

### Your Click Delegate

```
btnPtoPay.Click += delegate
{
    List<LineItem> selectedList = new List<LineItem>();

    for (int x = 0; x < tableGrid.ChildCount; x++)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCellFive);
        var tvSelectedAmount = (TextView)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCelltwo);
        var tvAmountPaid = (TextView)tableGrid.GetChildAt(x).FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtCelltwo);
        decimal totalM = 0; 
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {                        
            totalM = totalM+ Convert.ToDecimal(tvSelectedAmount.Text);   
            //Here how to get selected item, with all fields
            double selectedAmount = double.Parse(tvSelectedAmount.Text);
            double amountPaid = double.Parse(tvAmountPaid);

            selectedList.Add(new LineItem(totalM, amountPaid, selectedAmount));
        }
    };

    var fragmentTx = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    var feePay = new FeePaymentFragment(selectedList);
    fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.crealtabcontent, feePay, "feedPayFragmentTag").AddToBackStack("feePayfrg");
    fragmentTx.Commit();
};
```

Something along these lines will get you started with moving a selection from one place to another. From here you can re-instantiate the checked items in a smaller grid if you wish, or do calculations or whatever you want.

You may want to make changes that suit your application better, I only had a small amount of information to work with.

Comment: that's not what I was looking for. I need  some better way so that instead of getting each field one by one I can get total selected item.